# How to highlight area from start to end date in Excel using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, highlight

I have start and end dates given in Columns A and B. Then I choose a range which I want to look at  and generate a row of dates which starts from C1 and can end at any point. I need to highlight a row from start date to end date to the right of given dates. Is there a way to do this? I have no idea where to start...Help, please.
For Example,

I want to look at range from 5/2/2015 to 5/5/2015
Instead of zeros i need this area to be highlighted.

```
   A          B        C         D        E         F      G
1 start     end      5/2/2015 5/3/2015 5/3/2015 5/4/2015 5/52015
2 5/1/2015  5/3/2015 00000000000000000
3 5/2/2015  5/2/2015 00000000
4 5/4/2015  5/5/2015                            0000000000000000
```

Comment: Please don't post comments as separate answers. Take a look around this site and find some of the suggestions for posting good questions.

Comment: I'm not sure why you wish to use VBA for this when [Conditional Formatting](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) with a native worksheet formula is a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I found what I believe to be a typo in E1. I changed it to *5/4/2015* (one day in advance of D1) and adjusted F1:G1 to suit.

[image: Conditional formatting dates within other dates]

1. Select C2:G4 with C2 as the *active cell*.
2. Choose Home ► Conditional Formatting ► New Rule.
3. When the **New Formatting Rule** has opened, choose *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and supply the following in the *Format cells where this formula is true:* text box:
             `=AND(C$1>=$A2, C$1<=$B2)`
4. Click <kbd>Format</kbd> and choose some formatting changes. I chose a green *Fill*
5. Click <kbd>OK</kbd> to accept the formatting then <kbd>OK</kbd> again to create the new rule.

Your results should resemble the sample image provided at the beginning of this proposed solution.

If you need to expand the range, select C2 and go to Home ► Conditional Formatting ► Manage Rules. Change the *Applies to:* to reflect the new expanded range and click <kbd>OK</kbd> to save the changes.